# VBA: Opening a text file from URL to read

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file on my website that contains only the string "1.15" (for the version of the application I am writing). Upon initialization of the user form, I would like to read that file from its URL and have the string "1.15" returned so that I can check it against the application's version (stored as a const string).

Here is the format I'd like to have...

```
Const version As String = "1.14"
Const currentVersionURL As String = "http://mywebsite.com/currentversion.txt"

Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    If version <> GetCurrentVersionNumber() Then
        MsgBox "Please update the application."
    End If

End Sub

Function GetCurrentVersionNumber() As String

    ' What do I put here? :(

End Function
```

I am aware of the `Workbooks.OpenText` method, but I don't want to write the string into a workbook. I have tried using the `ADODB.LoadFromFile` and `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.Open` methods, but both are unable to read the file.

Any suggestions for what to fill `GetCurrentVersionNumber()` with would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Use the API URLDownloadToFile. Let me give you an example...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it doesn't directly answer your question, a simpler approach would be to make it an XML file instead of a text file.  There are more built-in tools to easily open an XML file from a URL.  The secondary advantage is that it also makes it more flexible, so you can more easily add new data elements to the XML file later on.

For instance, if you made a `http://mywebsite.com/currentversion.xml` file that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AppData>
    <Version>1.14</Version>
</AppData>
```

Then, in VB.NET you could easily read it like this:

```
Function GetCurrentVersionNumber() As String
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("http://mywebsite.com/currentversion.xml")
    Return doc.SelectSingleNode("/AppData/Version").InnerText
End Function
```

Or, in VBA, you could read it like this:

```
Function GetCurrentVersionNumber() As String
    Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument??  ' Where ?? is the version number, such as 30 or 60
    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument??
    doc.async = False
    doc.Load("http://mywebsite.com/currentversion.xml")
    GetCurrentVersionNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("/AppData/Version").Text
End Function
```

You will need to add a reference to the **Microsoft XML, v?.?** library, though.

Comment: This seems way more appropriate for the task at hand... thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out and report back with results.

Comment: I am having issues instantiating an XML document with the line `Dim doc As New XmlDocument()`. I get the following error from that line: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement". Do I need to include some references to use this? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to reference `system.xml.dll`, and you will need to add `Imports System.Xml` to the top of your code file.

Comment: Pardon by inexperience with VBA, but I don't see how to reference that file. I am looking in Tools>References and I cannot find it. Sorry. D:

Comment: Ah!  You originally had this tagged as VB.NET.  No wonder you were getting that end of statement expected error.  I thought that was strange.  Ok, let me update my answer.

Comment: My apologies... I typed in VB and it came up with VB.NET, so I thought they were the same. Thank you!

Comment: As always, `MSXML2.DOMDocument` means `MSXML2.DOMDocument30`. If you reference "Microsoft XML, v6.0" then it's probably better to delcare the variables as `MSXML2.DOMDocument60` - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: `Return doc.SelectSingleNode("/AppData/Version").InnerText` isn't correct syntax for VBA - replace with `GetCurrentVersionNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("/AppData/Version").InnerText` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you @barrowc -- I've made those changes accordingly. Unfortunately, I receive the error "Method or data member not found" for the `InnerText` member. Here is what I have:

`Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60`
`Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60`
`doc.Load "http://mywebsite.com/myfile.xml"`
`GetCurrentVersionNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("/version/").InnerText`

I have referenced Microsoft XML v6.0 and my XML file is formatted as follows:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`
`<version>1.15</version>`

Comment: Yes, @barrowc, thanks.  It's been a couple years since I've worked in VB6, so I'm getting rusty.

Comment: I just looked it up, and I think the equivalent property is `Text` instead of `InnerText`.  I updated my example.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would recommend having an outer document element, such as the `AppData` element in my example.  You can only have one document element in an xml document, so if you make the version the document element, then you won't be able add any other elements to the document in the future and still maintain backwards compatibility.  But, I suppose, if you're really sure it will never ever contain anything else....

Comment: @StevenDoggart I've changed it exactly as you have it in the example, but I get the error "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available." Is this due to the XML file, or the accessibility of it? Thank you for your help. :\

Comment: Try setting `doc.async = False` before calling the `Load` method.  If that works, let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick... thank you very much @StevenDoggart, barrowc, and Siddharth -- I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Const currentVersionURL As String = "http://mywebsite.com/currentversion.txt"
Const version As String = "1.14"

Dim Ret As Long

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If version <> GetCurrentVersionNumber() Then
        MsgBox "Please update the application."
    End If
End Sub

Function GetCurrentVersionNumber() As String
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Destination for the file
    strPath = TempPath & "currentversion.txt"

    '~~> Download the file
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, currentVersionURL, strPath, 0, 0)

    '~~> If downloaded
    If Ret = 0 Then
        Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

        Open "C:\MyFile.Txt" For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1

        GetCurrentVersionNumber = MyData
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to download the file"
        GetCurrentVersionNumber = ""
    End If
End Function

'~~> Get Users Temp Path
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

Comment: While I appreciate your solution, I'm going to go down the XML road. Thank you kindly!

Comment: No worries... :) @StevenDoggart gave a really nice solution :)